# Resize an image within a parent element class

Tags: css, ckeditor

This seems simple enough but I am trying to override a style class on an image tag.

A user uploads content and images using the CKEditor wysiwyg. The issue is if the user doesn't resize the image before posting and then I try to show their HTML on the page the image is wider than the container.

How can I override it with CSS?

```
<p class="post-content text-muted break-text mb-none">
    <p><img alt="" src="https://example.com/1234.png" style="height:1598px; width:1594px" /></p 
</p
```

I tried this css but couldn't override it.

```
<style>
    .post-content img {
        width:400px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Since this is user-generated content, I can't add a class directly to the img otherwise I would, if that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has a `<p>` tag inside a `<p>` tag so would likely have rendered as two separate paragraphs, and the one containing the image wouldn't have the `.post-content` class on it.

Aside from that, you might be best of with this CSS, as this will keep the image at 100% width but no larger than its actual size.

```
.post-content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: understood. Even if I try: ".post-content p img { " it still won't resize

Comment: does `.post-content img` not work? `.post-content` is the `<p>` tag so like I said the structure is unlikely to render as a `<p>` tag inside a `<p>` tag

Comment: ".post-content img" or ".post-content p img" both doesn't work. Trying to figure out if I need to do it through css or try a clever JQuery route